# Histograms and continuous queries in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I would like the histogram over one year - the distribution of values over a full year -  from a time series in InfluxDB. What is the right syntax for this query? All examples contain a group-by-time-clause, but that (naturally) results in multiple time units, each with its own histogram. I don't really know when that would be useful? Anyway, I tried this

```
select histogram(value,0.1) from series1 where time > '2013-09-25' and time < '2014-09-25'
```

which seems to produce the right answer. However, it takes quite a while to execute, so I want to turn it into a continuous query. As it says in the documentation that where clauses are ignored when creating continuous queries, I tried this:

```
select histogram(value,0.1) from series1 into series1hist
```

This doesn't seem to work, though. series1hist seems to be divided into time units, as if the query had contained a group-by-time-clause. How should it be done?

Comment: histogram function is not yet functional in 0.13 according to the documentation. https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/functions/#histogram